# Is it possible to "like" an OpenGraph Object?

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am having problems to link the Facebook Like buttons in my website with the OpenGraph Objects.

Since a couple of days, I have updated the metadata of my website declaring specific sites as different OG Objects. This is working fine, since
- the Facebook Debugger is accepting the URLs and recognizing them as OG Object with no errors
- the insights of my App shows me a very big increment of the Object Lifecycle from the moment these changes became live

At this point, I would have expected that every like button pressed in each of these sites would publish something similar to
"User1 likes a ObjectTitle on App"
but the message generated is still "User1 likes a link" or "User1 likes a page"

Is it really not possible to connect the original Facebook Like Button with an OpenGraph Object?
Do I need to create a "Built-In Like" to publish such a Story in a User's Timeline?
Do I miss something here? or is anyone having the same problem?

Thanks! I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really not possible to connect the original Facebook Like Button with an OpenGraph Object?

Yes, that is exactly what you are doing. All your URLS that have been debugged and liked are now objects on the Graph.

> Do I need to create a "Built-In Like" to publish such a Story in a User's Timeline?

Yes you need to use the built-in like action to achieve this, but Facebook will mostly likely reject your request to submit the action if your reasoning is not strong enough for not using the regular like button.

You need an object that is significantly different from a regular article page (e.g. a recipe)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have seen other websites where this functionality is provided, also through the normal Facebook Like button. For this reason, I wanted to avoid creating a Built-in Like Button with a new design and just use the Facebook one.  The objects of my site are defined as my_app_namespace:hotel or my_app_namespace:picture, types which are correctly included in my App's Open Graph and seem to be "accepted" by the debugger (at least no error is shown)

Comment: @RopertusPoris there is no reason for it not to be accepted by the debugger or your app settings. If the meta tags are valid, the debugger will accept it. Whatever sites you are seeing doing this are most likely partners with Facebook and have a beta functionality not available to everyone.